# Will I receive GCM messages if Android kill my app and if I do a Force Close from the settings?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm a newbie to Android development and I'm interested in two things which is connected to Google Cloud Messaging.

1. Does Android absolutely kill applications if they run for a long time in background as iOS does? And if so will I receive GCM notifications after my app was killed by Android?
2. Is there some difference between Force Close (from the settings menu) and when the app is killed by Android? And if I do Force Close will I receive GCM notifications?

Comment: @noundla,Could you please elaborate the point you telling?why we receive msg ,after force stopped.

Comment: @Noundla, no, if your process isn't running, you'll get result CANCELLED when you receive the GCM. Note this in your logcat: W/GCM/DMM﹕ broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=xxxx (has extras) }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 - yes, but if you install in your manifest a broadcast receiver that listens for the gcm, it will triggered anyway. What you will do with that event depends on your app. A common practice is to start an intent service that handles the message. It's up to you to make interact with the activities of your app.

2 - From android 3.1, if the user force closes your app, it will stop to be notified of any broadcast until the user does not start your app again. Check "Launch controls on stopped applications" [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. As i understood if I will do a Force Close i will not receive GCM notifications.
But I don't understand why. Here what I read in the docs:"A background service or application can override this behavior by adding the FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES flag to broadcast intents that should be allowed to activate stopped applications."
Can you please explain what is happened internally when i do a Force Close? And please comment that lines from the docs. Great thanks in advance!

Comment: What (I think) it happens is that if the application is flagged as stopped every broadcast intent (such as the one you intercept with your broadcast received) is blocked until the application exit from that state (which means after the first start / a restart after a forced block). This aims is to block unwanted application to execute in background without having being started or after a force close. It is a sort of protection because intercepting broadcasts you can execute code in background even if the os killed your app.