# GCM message not arriving until App is either running or in background

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have successfully implemented GCM and messages successfully arrive to my devices when the App is in running and background states.

But when the App is in a closed state, some devices receive the message and some do not. To get the message, I have to start the application again.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"     />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<permission
    android:name="com.example.hp.abcd.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.hp.abcd.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.hp.abcd.REGISTER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Subject"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.hp.abcd.Subject" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Message"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.hp.abcd.MESSAGE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.hp.abcd.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action  android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.hp.abcd" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService" />
</application>
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

}

GCMNotificationIntent service

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {  

public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

public static final String TAG = "GCMNotificationIntentService";

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                    + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                .equals(messageType)) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                Log.i(TAG,
                        "Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ "+ SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }

            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

            sendNotification(""
                    + extras.get(Config.MESSAGE_KEY));
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM,yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat t = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String strDate = d.format(c.getTime());
    String strTime = t.format(c.getTime());

    db.addContact(new Contact(msg, strDate, strTime));


     PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, Message.class), 0);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gcm_logo)
            .setContentTitle("India")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setSound(soundUri);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
}
}
```

Comment: please help me as soon as possible

Answer (score 2):

If you "force close" an app, then it will become unresponsive to all broadcasts until the user starts it again.

If you "remove from recents" (like on some devices, long hold the "home" key) then this is not a force close, and even if the app is in the background, it will continue to receive messages.

See this post here: [Will I receive GCM messages if Android kill my app and if I do a Force Close from the settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528000/will-i-receive-gcm-messages-if-android-kill-my-app-and-if-i-do-a-force-close-fro)

Comment: not asking force close just close condition also not receive message

Comment: just pressing home button and closing my app also not allow to receive in some mobile but in some message is comming

Comment: are you processing the messages in your receiver? Not a good practice, but if you are trying to do the processing in an `Activity` and it was destroyed by Android for memory purposes, it will probably not process as you expect - it will get reconstructed. You should process the GCM intent in an `IntentService` or regular `Service`

Comment: how can i do so? any help

Comment: You need to post your `Receiver` code - and any `Activity` code that does the processing

Comment: ok now tell me i give posted Broadcast receiver and GCMNotification Intent

Comment: Please help its important

Comment: How many devices have you tried? And does the intent not arrive or it is empty from GCM or what? A properly registered device will receive the intent - you are using package name "com.example" - which is not good, but shouldn't prevent testing on a few devices.

Comment: but few devices like samsung star gets but devices like mi3 and samsung duos donot get when i run the app message was coming when i pressed home button message  was coming but after long pressing home button and clearing recent app message stopped coming

Comment: what is the solution for this

Comment: in my manifest  receiver i have given com.example.hp.abcd.GcmBroadcastReceiver but as i read i have to give                android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
but after applying this no message was comming