# GCM notifications are completely lost (no visual in status bar) after app is force closed

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

This only applies after force closing the app. Everything works as expected when the app is running in foreground/background or simply not in the "stopped" state.

I've been sending different notifications to my Android device to check its behaviour.

Regardless of the contents of the GCM notification (with/without notification/data payloads or priority and other flag values):

1. The visual notification at the status bar is never shown
2. The listener service on the app never gets called **(I know this is expected behaviour)**

I don't understand why case 1 doesn't work. Is this also expected behaviour? I know the app is not running and can't be triggered by a broadcast but the UI notification should at least be shown.

Besides, once I open the app, I was expecting to receive these notifications but they simply aren't received. They are completely lost.
New notifications I send after re-opening the app are received as expected.

I appreciate all the help and hints you can give.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528000/will-i-receive-gcm-messages-if-android-kill-my-app-and-if-i-do-a-force-close-fro.

Comment: Hi @adjuremods, I've read that topic before posting and, although it's related, it doesn't answer my question about the visual notification at the status bar (1). I know there are a lot of questions about this already but none seem to discuss this issue in particular.