# GCM The messages that are send when device is off don't storage and receive when restart

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Please i need help. My app receive messages when the app is open or in background, but if i off the device or force close app, all messages never can received when restart the app. I read a lot of things but i don't find anything. Please there are my classes.

1 Someone send me a message. And I receive the message.

2 I force close my app or off my device.

3 Someone send me a message, but my device is off.

4 I put my device on, and restart the app. I dont receive any messages, but if someone send me a new message now, i receive this message.

Only when the app is in Background or front. But when I restart the app after the app is killed, i dont receive the storage messages from gcm.

This is ReceiverClass:

```
public class MSGReceiver  extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
    msgrcv.putExtra("msg", extras.getString("msg"));
    msgrcv.putExtra("fromu", extras.getString("fromu"));
    msgrcv.putExtra("fromname", extras.getString("name"));

    if(extras.getString("fromu")!=null && extras.getString("msg")!=null){
        try{
            SharedPreferences blindDate = context.getSharedPreferences("datosblind",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ConexionSQLite conexion = new ConexionSQLite(context);
            int id = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("fromu"));
            int idUser = Integer.parseInt(blindDate.getString("REG_FROM",""));
            int order = conexion.getSize(id, idUser);
            conexion.insertNewMessage(id, extras.getString("msg"), order+1, "false", idUser);
            conexion.insertNewSize(id, order+1, idUser);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),MSGService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);


}
```

}

This is ServiceClass:

```
public class MSGService extends IntentService {

SharedPreferences prefs;
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
NotificationManager manager;


public MSGService() {
    super("MSGService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("datosblind", 0);


    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            Log.e("L2C","Error");

        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            Log.e("L2C","Error");

        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {

            if(!prefs.getString("CURRENT_ACTIVE","").equals(extras.getString("fromu"))) {
                if(prefs.getInt("iniciadaLaSesion", 0)==1)
                    sendNotification(extras.getString("msg"), extras.getString("fromu"), extras.getString("name"));
            }
        }
    }
    MSGReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg,String mobno,String name) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("mobno", mobno);
    args.putString("name", name);
    args.putString("msg", msg);
    Intent chat = new Intent(this, Conversacion.class);
    chat.putExtra("INFO", args);
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notification.setContentTitle(name);
    notification.setContentText(msg);
    notification.setTicker("Blind Date: " + name);
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    notification.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sonidonotificacion));

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1000,
            chat, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    notification.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    notification.setAutoCancel(true);
    manager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(Integer.parseInt(mobno), notification.build()); 
}
```

}

This is the manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.expansion.minlove.MSGReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.expansion.minlove" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.expansion.minlove.MSGService" />
```

And this is the request of Server:

```html
exports.send = function(fromn,fromu,to,msg,callback) {

user.find({mobno: to},function(err,users){
var len = users.length;
if(len == 0){
callback({'response':"Failure"});
}else{
 var to_id = users[0].reg_id;
 var name = users[0].name;

request(
    { method: 'POST', 
    uri: 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization':'key=********mjxGkTrOnH6dE'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
  "registration_ids" : [to_id],
  "data" : {
    "msg":msg,
    "fromu":fromu,
    "name":fromn
  },
})
    }
  , function (error, response, body) {

   callback({'response':"Success"});
    }
  )
}});

}
```

Please i need help. 
I'm gonna go crazy.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528000/will-i-receive-gcm-messages-if-android-kill-my-app-and-if-i-do-a-force-close-fro

Comment: No, because my problem not is notifications, my problem is when i restart the app i want to receive the storage messages that are send when the device is off or the app is force close. Only i want that gcm storage messages and send me when i restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you define WAKE_LOCK permission for your app in AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Yes, i have all permissions that i need: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="com.expansion.minlove.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" /><uses-permission android:name="com.expansion.minlove.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />